# jQuery dynamic fill in form fields with table data

Tags: jquery, html, forms, html-table

I have created a form in a modal box with a table. When you click on a table row it populates a form on the parent page. This is working great but I can't get the values to change when I click on another table row. Because I'm using IDs it only takes the values from the first table row. I am open to changing to classes but I tried this and it didn't help.

Please can anyone help me with this. The code is below.

Modal Form with Table

```
<div id="modal_form" title="Address Search">
<form id="modal_form">
<ul>
    <li><label for="name">Search by street description</label>
        <input type="text" name="street_description" id="street_description" />
        <input type="button" id="search_button" class="form_button" value="Search"></li>
</ul>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="table-data">
              <tbody><tr>
                <td width="200px"><a href="#">Street</a></td>
                <td width="200px"><a href="#">Suburb</a></td>
                <td width="200px"><a href="#">City</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id="address_street">Harambee Road</td>
                <td id="address_suburb">Onerai </td>
                <td id="address_city">Onerai Rural</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id="address_street">Hutchinson Road</td>
                <td id="address_suburb">Onerai </td>
                <td id="address_city">Onerai Rural</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id="address_street">Kauri Road</td>
                <td id="address_suburb">Onerai </td>
                <td id="address_city">Onerai Rural</td>
              </tr>
        </tbody></table><!-- /table#table-data -->
</form>
```

Javascript (This is where I need to differentiate between the table rows)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#table-data tr').click(function () {
$('#street_name').val( $('#address_street').text() )
$('#suburb').val( $('#address_suburb').text() )
$('#city').val( $('#address_city').text() )})
});
</script>
```

Parent Form, where the form fields are populated

```
<form id="profile">
<ul>
<li><label for="street_number">Street Number</label><input id="street_number" type="text" placeholder="Street Number" name="street_number" ><input type="button" class="form_button" id="find_address" value="Find Address"></li>
<li><label for="street_name">Street Name</label><input id="street_name" type="text" placeholder="Street Name" name="street_name"  disabled="disabled" ></li>
<li><label for="suburb">Suburb</label><input id="suburb" type="text" placeholder="Suburb" name="suburb"  disabled="disabled" ></li>
<li><label for="city">City</label><input id="city" type="text" placeholder="City" name="city" disabled="disabled" ></li>
<li><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save"></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Thanks for any help you can give, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs must be unique, so this is not going to work:

```
<td id="address_street">Harambee Road</td>
...
<td id="address_street">Hutchinson Road</td>
```

I would give each of the *rows* an ID, and have all of the columns use the same *class*:

```
<tr id="row1">
  <td class="address_street">Harambee Road</td>
  <td class="address_suburb">Onerai </td>
  <td class="address_city">Onerai Rural</td>
</tr>
<tr id="row2">
  <td class="address_street">Hutchinson Road</td>
  <td class="address_suburb">Onerai </td>
  <td class="address_city">Onerai Rural</td>
</tr>
<tr id="row3">
  <td class="address_street">Kauri Road</td>
  <td class="address_suburb">Onerai </td>
  <td class="address_city">Onerai Rural</td>
</tr>
```

Your JavaScript would change to be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table-data tr').click(function () {
      var curRowId = $(this).attr("id");
      $('#street_name').val( $('#' + curRowId + ' td.address_street').text() );
      $('#suburb').val( $('#' + curRowId + ' td.address_suburb').text() );
      $('#city').val( $('#' + curRowId + ' td.address_city').text() );
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea how I could modify my javascript to incorporate your solution. I'm still a beginner and to use your solution I would create multiple scripts just targeting each row ID. I know there must be an easier way to do this, any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Sorry disregard my above comment, I obviously commented while you were busy, I'll try your code out now, thanks again :)

Comment: @Clinton: Sorry, I missed some spaces in the JavaScript; updated.

Comment: GENIUS - It works thanks so much for all the help and effort, I was really struggling with this one, I'll try use var more in the future. Cheers :)